# Memory usage explodes when using CSSApply within function

Tags: css, r

I observed some weird behavior when using the command `cssApply` from the library `CSS` inside a function.

Basically, each time I call the function, R uses an additional 0.5Mb of memory. Since I want use the function to extract data from roughly 20.000 webpages, R soon crashes because it has memory problems.

Here is some sample code that reproduces the problem:

```
library(CSS)

f <- function() {

url <- "http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/2049768676/schoolhaus-a4"
page.o <- readLines(url)
page <- htmlParse(page.o)
name <- cssApply(page, "#name", cssCharacter)
return(name)
}

x <- character(200)

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
x[i] <- f()  
print(i)
flush.console()
}
```

First I thought that using a data.frame was the problem, but then I figured out that `cssApply` is the problem. If I comment it out, memory usage stays more or less constant.

If anybody has an idea what's the problem, I would very much appreciate their help.

Thanks very much,

Dainis

Comment: I'm assuming this is merely a (bad) example, since the function never uses `name` or even `d.out`; it must be just a proof of concept. I've tried to reproduce your assertion of memory waste (with dozens of replications) and see very little increase, certainly not 500KB *each call* (win7, R_3.1.0, CSS_1.0.2, string_0.6.2, XML_3.98-1.1). Occasionally R increases its memory size, but this could be due to many things (and in general is very difficult to nail down). Perhaps `sessionInfo()` would help us help you.

Comment: Hi Evans, thanks very much for your comment.
You are right, my example code was not 100% clean & reproducible. I just edited it, I hope it works now. As you can see, I try to extract data from kickstarter-projects.

Comment: And here is my Session-Info:

    R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252 
    [2] LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
    [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   
    [5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
    [7] base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] CSS_1.0.2     stringr_0.6.2 XML_3.98-1.1 

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_3.1.0

Comment: Have you looked at package `XML` at all?  There is a function, `free` that cleans up memory on some object classes.

Comment: Thanks Richard, no I have not looked at that.

Comment: I read a little about the function cssApply, and you are right, it is actually a wrapper for the `xpathSApply` function in the XML library. 
I have only a very limited understanding of XML, but does this mean that in my code above `page` is the XML document and `cssApply` references it. And if I do not release the XML object, it stays in memory. This would explain why memory usage increases with each call.

Comment: But unfortunately, including `free(page)` in the function does not help.

Comment: Aha, I only looked at memory allocation in my Windows Task manager at it still was increasing after adding `free(page)`. But I read somewhere that the operating system might not reclaim the memory until it really is needed. So I'll run the full script with the full set of 30,000 pages and report here whether it still crashes once the memory limit is reached...

Comment: Hi all,
unfortunately I was not really able to solve this problem. What I did in the end was simply transferring the script to a more powerful computer with enough RAM such that the script did no longer crash. But thanks anyways for your efforts!